# Using rails associations for models (undefined method `has_one')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am trying to open up the registration page to create an account (which has a payment) and I get this error "undefined method `has_one' for Account:Class".  I am not using a database so I am not using active record.  Is there a way around this?

account.rb

```
class Account
    include ActiveModel::Model

    attr_accessor :company_name, :phone_number,
                            :card_number, :expiration_month, :expiration_year, :cvv

    has_one :payment
end
```

payment.rb

```
class Payment
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :card_number, :expiration_month, :expiration_year, :cvv

  belongs_to :account

  validates :card_number, presence: true, allow_blank: false
  validates :cvv, presence: true, allow_blank: false
end
```

account_controller.rb

```
class AccountController < ApplicationController
def register
    @account = Account.new
  end
end
```

Comment: Not really, you'll need a database.  You can implement the functionality yourself but the web is stateless so you'll lose it as soon as you change page unless you pass around a load of variables.  Is there any reason you're wanting to do this without a database?

Comment: @japed I am doing just the front end and the backend services touch the database

Answer (score 0):

`has_one` and  `belongs_to` are not part of `ActiveModel::Model`. They are part of `ActiveRecord` as they specify how to get the objects from the relational database.

In your case I guess you should just have another attribute `payment` in `Account` model.

```
class Account
   include ActiveModel::Model

   attr_accessor :company_name, :phone_number,
                 :card_number, :expiration_month, 
                 :expiration_year, :cvv,
                 :payment

end
```

and then in your controller do something like

```
class AccountController < ApplicationController
   def register
     @account = Account.new
     @account.payment = Payment.new
   end
 end
```

or you could event initialize the payment in initializer of `Account` class. Also it seems like `Payment` does not need to know about `Account`.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly this is a very old question, but I ran across it while trying to solve a similar problem and eventually found that solutions have arisen in the intervening years.  So, given the only posted answer was never marked as "accepted," I thought I'd throw my hat in the ring.

Rails 5 introduced the ActiveRecord Attributes API, and by way of [this post by Karol Galanciak describing it](https://karolgalanciak.com/blog/2016/12/04/introduction-to-activerecord-and-activemodel-attributes-api/) you may be interested to take a look at a [gem created by the same author](https://github.com/Azdaroth/active_model_attributes).  If you took a look at the issues for that gem, you might be interested to read in [issue #12](https://github.com/Azdaroth/active_model_attributes/issues/12) that the Attributes API functionality is now present in ActiveModel, though it is not publicly documented (the `module Attributes` is flagged with `#:nodoc:`, see [attributes.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/attributes.rb)) and perhaps should not be relied upon to be consistent from version to version, though the wind, soft as it may seem at times, certainly seems to be blowing in the direction of a "public" `ActiveModel::Attributes` API.

Nevertheless, if you were to throw caution to the wind and use the not-quite-public `ActiveModel::Attributes` you could do something like this (note: I cobbled this together for my own project and rewrote it a bit to fit your example, your needs may be different than mine):

```
class AccountPayment
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :card_number, :expiration_month, :expiration_year, :cvv

  validates :card_number, presence: true, allow_blank: false
  validates :cvv, presence: true, allow_blank: false
end

class AccountPaymentType < ActiveModel::Type::Value
  def cast(value)
    AccountPayment.new(value)
  end
end

class Account
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes #being bad and using private API!

  attr_accessor :company_name, :phone_number, :card_number, :expiration_month, :expiration_year, :cvv

  attribute :payment, :account_payment
end
```

And somewhere you must register the type - in rails it'd be in an initializer, but in my code I just stashed it at the top of the equivalent of your `Account` model:

```
ActiveModel::Type.register(:account_payment, AccountPaymentType)
```